# VnPy - ImportError: No module named vnctpmd

Tags: python-import

I just cloned [VnPy](https://github.com/vnpy/vnpy), and I am trying to run VnTrader on a Ubuntu 16.04 Machine, as mentioned in the [VnPy Starter Guide](https://medium.com/p/911a81539302). I followed step by step, but when I run

```
python vnpy/examples/VnTrader/run.py
```

I get the following Import Error. What is the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 28, in <module>
    from vnpy.trader.gateway import (ctpGateway, ibGateway)
  File "/home/alessandro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vnpy-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/vnpy/trader/gateway/ctpGateway/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ctpGateway import CtpGateway
  File "/home/alessandro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vnpy-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/vnpy/trader/gateway/ctpGateway/ctpGateway.py", line 16, in <module>
    from vnpy.api.ctp import MdApi, TdApi, defineDict
  File "/home/alessandro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vnpy-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/vnpy/api/ctp/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .vnctpmd import MdApi
ImportError: No module named vnctpmd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImportError: No module named vnctpmd
```

The [vnctpmd](https://github.com/vnpy/vnpy/tree/master/vnpy/api/ctp/vnctpmd) module, is the API interface for CTP broker of the VnPy package. As for every other API interface, you need to first build it, and then import it.

In your case, you probably **didn't build the CTP interface** when prompted during the installation of VnPy, so now run.py can't import the module.

```
Do you need 'CTP' interface? No
```

**Solution A: I don't need CTP interface**

If you don't need CTP interface you can open [run.py](https://github.com/vnpy/vnpy/blob/master/examples/VnTrader/run.py) commenting the parts relative to CTP (and also relative to all the other interfaces you didn't build)

```
# /examples/VnTrader/run.py script
# this version runs with only the IB interface built

# encoding: UTF-8

# 重载sys模块，设置默认字符串编码方式为utf8
try:
    reload         # Python 2
except NameError:  # Python 3
    from importlib import reload

import sys
reload(sys)

try:
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
except AttributeError:
    pass

# 判断操作系统
import platform
system = platform.system()

# vn.trader模块
from vnpy.event import EventEngine
from vnpy.trader.vtEngine import MainEngine
from vnpy.trader.uiQt import createQApp
from vnpy.trader.uiMainWindow import MainWindow

# 加载底层接口
from vnpy.trader.gateway import ibGateway

# ### here comment the interfaces you don't need
# from vnpy.trader.gateway import (ctpGateway, ibGateway)


if system == 'Linux':
    # from vnpy.trader.gateway import xtpGateway
    pass
elif system == 'Windows':
    from vnpy.trader.gateway import (femasGateway, xspeedGateway,
                                     secGateway)

# 加载上层应用
from vnpy.trader.app import (riskManager, ctaStrategy, 
                             spreadTrading, algoTrading)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """主程序入口"""
    # 创建Qt应用对象
    qApp = createQApp()

    # 创建事件引擎
    ee = EventEngine()

    # 创建主引擎
    me = MainEngine(ee)

    # 添加交易接口
    # me.addGateway(ctpGateway)
    me.addGateway(ibGateway)

    if system == 'Windows':
        me.addGateway(femasGateway)
        me.addGateway(xspeedGateway)
        me.addGateway(secGateway)

    if system == 'Linux':
        # me.addGateway(xtpGateway)
    pass

    # 添加上层应用
    me.addApp(riskManager)
    me.addApp(ctaStrategy)
    me.addApp(spreadTrading)
    me.addApp(algoTrading)

    # 创建主窗口
    mw = MainWindow(me, ee)
    mw.showMaximized()

    # 在主线程中启动Qt事件循环
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Solution B: I need CTP interface**

In case you need CTP, you can just reinstall vnpy with the command

```
bash install.sh
```

and when prompted 'do you need CTP' answer Yes